# Custom package in EagleCAD not aligning to grid

Tags: eaglecad

I'm trying to make a custom package in eagle, and somehow the pads of my part got misaligned w.r.t. the grid.

[image]

Is there any convenient way to correct for this when it happens?

I know about the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd> for an individual component, is there a way to do something like that for a whole group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pads you are placing are off the grid when they are supposed to be on the grid, you can select the pad using the Info button and type the desired X and Y coordinates manually.

If you have lots of pads that are all mis-aligned by the same amount, there's a trick you can do using the grid. Say, for example, all of the pads are off by 0.015 inches. Change the grid spacing to 0.015 inches, select all of the pads using the Group tool, select the Move tool, right-click and select "Move Group", and slide all of the parts over by one grid spacing. Then change your grid spacing back to whatever you had before.

Comment: Yeah I know about the grid button. Say the grid is changed (say .65 to 1.0), when components are moved they shift 1.0 relative to their current location. I was wondering if there was a way to get them to snap to the new grid.

Comment: There is no way to do that automatically that I'm aware of. I just select the part using the Info button and type the desired X and Y coordinates manually.

Comment: Now that I have a better understanding of why you asked the question, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there anyways to set the X Y coordinates for a group of parts though? It seems that only works for one component. Sorry I should have made it clear I am currently making a new part, so all the pads are individual components.

Comment: See what I wrote in my edited answer. The last paragraph is for moving a group together.

Comment: Gotcha, so the brute force method is the correct way.

Comment: If by "brute force" you mean using the Group and Move tools to move them together, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the ALT spacing to a very small value and after you group the pads and hit the Move Group command you can press ALT and move them however you want according to the ALT grid spacing set below the normal grid spacing (the same window).

Comment: @Ben - This is how I'd do it to, **except** I'd set the ALT value to *exactly* the amount by which the pads need moving. Then it is robust and easy. This might take two steps if the X and Y are different distance misaligned. In that case, set ALT for one axis, move everything, change ALT for the other axis, one more move group, and its all done.

Answer (score 0):

In case of SCH mismatching grid in the sch,

Run the snap-on-grid-sch.ULP in the schematic. the components automatically fix to 100 mil /0.1 inch grid in sch.

Then you can run ERC and fix the unconnected errors. You must check the ERC after that ULP.
Its working 100%.

In package. you need to align the pad as per the datasheet.  you can use 1.27 mm is the default center grid for your tplace construction. Otherwise you can change the grid as much low as you can.